# Navigation With Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I created navigation with a bottom bar and the bottom bar has (Home, Cart, Favorite, and Profile)
and I connect every thing each other well but when click on the favorite icon the app will crash and the message error talks about the Activity can't handle the interface with hilt I will provide the error message below

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bitio.efashion, PID: 7874
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class
com.bitio.efashion.FashionActivity does not implement interface
dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface
dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager
at dagger.hilt.EntryPoints.get(EntryPoints.java:62)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.createInternal(
HiltViewModelFactory.java:149)
```

and I all dependencies here

```
  // Navigation
    api("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
    api("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0")

    // Dagger-Hilt
    api("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44")
```

Here my Activity

@AndroidEntryPoint
class FashionActivity : ComponentActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        val isDarkTheme by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }

        EFashionTheme(darkTheme = isDarkTheme) {
            BottomNavigationBar(
                favoriteViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
                profileViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
                authenticationViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
                orderStatusViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am expected that to work well because, and I tried to solve it by changing the version of the dependencies

Comment: Did put the annotation @AndroidEntryPoint on your main activity?

Comment: Yes, I did
But when I pass the viewModel from Activity to NavGraph then to screens it will work but in the first status doesn't work

Comment: Can you show me the FashionActivity's code?

Comment: Sure, you can read my question again I edited it

Comment: @sajjadio try matching the versions of hilt and hilt compiler